# I get no such file or directory when moving dist folder contents from gitlab to aws server instance

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am new to Gitlab CI/CD and trying to fix this all day long but nothing works. I am trying to move the dist folder generated by gitlab runner after build stage to aws ec2-instance folder location. I am currently implementing CI/CD pipeline using Gitlab and this is how my `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like:

```
# Node Image for docker on which code will execute
image: node:latest

# This is the stages / task to perfom in jobs
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

# caching for reuse 
cache:
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  paths:
  - node_modules/

# This command is run before the execution of stages
before_script:
  - npm install

# Job One for making build
build_testing_branch:
  stage: build
  script:
    - node --max_old_space_size=4096 --openssl-legacy-provider ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=dev-build --build-optimizer
  only: ['testing']

# Job Two for deploy build to server
deploy_testing_branch:
  stage: deploy

  before_script:
        - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
        # - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
        - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
        # - apt-get update -y
        # - apt-get -y install rsync

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/

  script:
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - ssh -p22 ubuntu@$SERVER_IP "rm -r /usr/share/nginx/user-host/ui-user-host/dist/; mkdir /usr/share/nginx/user-host/ui-user-host/dist/"
    - scp -P22 -r  $CI_PROJECT_DIR/dist/ ubuntu@$SERVER_IP:/usr/share/nginx/user-host/ui-user-host/dist/

  only: ['testing']
```

The build process works just fine with success confirmation, but the deployment stage fails because I get:

```
$scp -P22 -r  $CI_PROJECT_DIR/dist/ ubuntu@$SERVER_IP:/usr/share/nginx/user-host/ui-user-host/dist/
/builds/user-live/ui-user-host/dist: No such file or directory
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
```

So, I dont understand why its not able to locate dist folder in above location. If i correctly understand this should be available on the gitlab runner's filesystem. Is it because scp command is not right?

EDIT:

I also tried with

```
- scp -P22 -r  dist/ ubuntu@$SERVER_IP:/usr/share/nginx/user-host/ui-user-host/dist/
```

and

```
- scp -P22 -r  dist/* ubuntu@$SERVER_IP:/usr/share/nginx/user-host/ui-user-host/dist/
```

but no luck!

Comment: Aren't you creating the dist in `build_testing_branch` and trying to get it in the then next job `deploy_testing_branch`. You will have to add the artifacts the one which you gave in `deploy_testing_branch` to `build_testing_branch` job.


And just check if its available in the `deploy_testing_branch` with a `ls`.

Comment: @Origin yes I tried this yesterday and it worked. I created artifact in build_testing_branch stage by adding this in multi line format:
```artifacts: paths: - dist```
and changed dist folder line to this ```- scp -P22 -r  dist ubuntu@$SERVER_IP:/usr/share/nginx/user-host/ui-user-host/dist/```
it works now!

Comment: I have added an answer. Please consider accepting it if it has helped u, so that it can also be use-full for others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building your `dist` folder in `build_testing_branch` job and trying to access it in `deploy_testing_branch` for this to work you have to give the dist folder as artifact in `build_testing_branch` job (since dist is created there) and not in deploy_testing_branch.